# how to search id of a tensor in a dictionary without for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have a tensor like this:

```
idx = [[1, 2, 3], 
       [8, 0, 10]]
```

I have a dict like this:

```
docs = {'computer': {'1': 1, '3': 5, '8': 2},
        'politics':{'0': 2, '1': 2, '3': 1}}
```

I want to create a dictionary like this out of the `idx` and `docs`:

```
mydic ={'1': 3, '1_2': 0, '1_3': 2, '2': 0,'2_3':0, '3':6,
        '8':2, '8_0':0, '8_10': 0, '0':2, '0_10':0, '10':0}
```

How can I do that without looping through my tensor?

If I want to explain what is happening here, per elements in each dimension, for example `[1,2,3]`, I look into `docs`, I compute the frequency by summing up the value(as `1` being summed `3`) of each element. I also consider the co-occurrences. `docs` is a dict of dict and each dictionary represents a document. I show the co-occurrence of 1 and 2 with `1_2`.

Is it doable I do this without iteration through the tensor? if so, how.
I did something but it uses the for loop.

Comment: _docs is a dict of dict_ In the example you shared `docs` is a set. Please clarify the operation you're trying to perform.

Comment: @AMC Thank you for following my question. Could you let me know where I mentioned `set`? the `idx` is two dimensional tensor but `docs` is a dict.

Comment: _but `docs` is a dict_ That may be the case in your code, but not in what you shared above. I checked with `type()`, just to be sure.

Comment: @AMC Thank you so much for pointing this out. my mistake. I just updated it

Comment: Please provide the complete source code and the loop solution approach that you have used.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Thank you for following with my question. Actually right now I broke down the question to two question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699845/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-tensor-in-tensorflow and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711079/how-to-create-a-co-occurrence-tensor-out-of-two-tensor-in-tensorflow . and you can see my for loop over there. though I got better solution for that part and still stuck in the second part. Do you mind having a look at it?