# How to convert a dictionary into a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the dictionary I have:

```py
docs = {'computer': {'1': 1, '3': 5, '8': 2},
        'politics': {'0': 2, '1': 2, '3': 1}}
```

I want to create a `9 * 2 tensor` like this:

```py
[
    [0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Here, because the max item is 8 so we have 9 rows. But, the number of rows and columns can increase based on the dictionary.

I have tried to implement this using `for-loop` though as the dictionary is big it's not efficient at all and also it implemented using the list I need that to be a `tensor`.

```py
maxr = 0
for i, val in docs.items():
    for j in val.keys():
        if int(j) > int(maxr):
            maxr = int(j)

final_lst = []
for val in docs.values():
    lst = [0] * (maxr+1)
    for j, val2 in sorted(val.items()):
        lst[int(j)] = val2
    final_lst.append(lst)

print(final_lst)
```

Comment: Have you tried something? What is your minimal effort?

Comment: @ventaquil thanks for following my question. Sorry I forgot to include what I have tried. update it in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with using `pandas` and `numpy`, here's how you can do it.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# Creates a dataframe with keys as index and values as cell values. 
df  = pd.DataFrame(docs)

# Create a new set of index from min and max of the dictionary keys. 
new_index = np.arange( int(df.index.min()),
                       int(df.index.max())).astype(str)

# Add the new index to the existing index and fill the nan values with 0, take a transpose of dataframe. 

new_df = df.reindex(new_index).fillna(0).T.astype(int)

#          0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
#computer  0  1  0  5  0  0  0  0
#politics  2  2  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

If you just want the array, you can call  `array = new_df.values`.

```
#[[0 1 0 5 0 0 0 0]
# [2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0]]
```

If you want tensor, then you can use `tf.convert_to_tensor(new_df.values)`

Comment: thank you so much for answering this. Actually I need my final result to be a Tensor as later I need to use it in another tensor.

Comment: @sariii its easy to convert a numpy array to tensor

Comment: Thank you so much, `int(df.index.max())` needs to be `int(df.index.max())+1` otherwise it ignores `8`.