# Tensorflow 2 custom dataset Sequence

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset in a python dictionary. The structure is as follow:

`data.data['0']['input'],data.data['0']['target'],data.data['0']['length']`

Both `input` and `target` are arrays of size `(n,)` and `length` is an int.

I have created a class object with `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` and specify `__getitem__` as this:

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx = str(idx)

        return {
            'input': np.asarray(self.data[idx]['input']),
            'target': np.asarray(self.data[idx]['target']),
            'length': self.data[idx]['length']
               }
```

How can I iterate over such dataset using `tf.data.Dataset`? I am getting this error if I try to use `from_tensor_slices`

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the dictionary to a tensor as proposed here [convert a dictionary to a tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699845/how-to-convert-a-dictionary-into-a-tensor-in-tensorflow)
or change the dictionary to a text file or to a tfrecords. Hope this would help you!

Comment: That's what I needed to do! Still some useful functionalities that pytorch supports and tf doesnt!